# C++ modules: module implementation units for unnecessary recompilation?

Tags: c++, compilation, c++-modules

Recently watched video from CppCon 2017: Boris Kolpackov “Building C++ Modules”
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8EbDcLQAoc

Approximately at 31:35 he starts explaining that we should still use header/source splitting and shows 3 reasons. The first reason:

If you have both declarations/definitions in the same place when you touch this module all other modules that depend on the **module interface** (BMI) will be recompiled.

And that I didn't like at all. It sounded like we are still in 90s and compilers cannot be smart enough to see difference in BMI-related changes and implementation related changes. As I see it, compilers are able to quickly scan each module and generate only BMI from it. And if BMI is not changed - don't recompile other modules that depend on it.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: That is a complete tooling implementation detail.  Most build systems are simplistic and rely on time stamps of the files to decide what needs to be compiled.  But this can easily be improved, as demonstrated for the past 10 years in everybody's favorite [C++ language extension](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2011/04/05/build-related-improvement-in-vs2010-sp1/).

Comment: It would be implementation detail, but if it is influencing the whole modules proposal, then it's not.   Some time ago I was under the impression C++ modules would look like Java or C# modules - 1 file per module. I was looking forward to stop using header/source splitting, because I find it pretty annoying to always change function parameters that are duplicated in 2 places in different files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of that talk later said the recompilation issue is a matter of implementation. Quoting the article [*Common C++ Modules TS Misconceptions*](https://build2.org/article/cxx-modules-misconceptions.xhtml#single-file) by Boris Kolpackov:

> It turns out a lot of people would like to get rid of the header/source split (or, in modules terms, interface/implementation split) and keep everything in a single file. You *can* do that in Modules TS: with modules (unlike headers) you *can* define non-inline functions and variables in module interface units. So if you want to keep everything in a single file, you *can*.

and

> Now, keeping everything in a single file may have negative build performance implications but it appears a smart enough build system in cooperation with the compiler should be able to overcome this. See this [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/77fgbw/cppcon_2017_boris_kolpackov_building_c_modules/domj8be/) for details.

Quoting [Gor Nishanov](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/77fgbw/cppcon_2017_boris_kolpackov_building_c_modules/don5vih/) (the Project Editor of Coroutines TS) from the linked thread:

> That is up to you how to structure your code. Module TS does not impose on you how you decompose your module into individual files. If you want, you can implement your entire module in the interface file (thus you will have C# like experience), or you can partition your module into an interface and one or more implementation files.

The Project Editor of [Modules TS](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4720.pdf), Gabriel Dos Reis, [commented on the MSVC implementation](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/77fgbw/cppcon_2017_boris_kolpackov_building_c_modules/doo81bg/):

> Ideally, only semantics-relevant changes should trigger recompilation keyed on the IFC.

(As a side note, the Modules TS [has now been approved](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/7unskl/c_modules_working_draft_n4720/dtmlvcr/) and sent to ISO for publication.)

Comment: A content-aware build system (*e.g.*, SCons) can easily notice the same BMI being regenerated and halt the propagation of rebuilding.  But even changes to comments could easily change diagnostic/debugging information included in a BMI (absent some “raw” option, perhaps).